# Nextjs & next-auth: how to handle dynamic navbar based on if user is authed or not?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I've been starting to build projects with Nextjs a few months ago, and this is something that always caused me trouble.

In the Navbar, I'm using next-auth useSession() hook to check if the user is authenticated, but while that occurs, the user is not authenticated, and the navbar hides some links. After a moment (or seconds if I'm testing with no cache and worse internet), the Nextjs recognizes that the user is authed and the navbar shows the rest of the links, causing a horrible and undesired layout shift.

What approach should I have to improve this situation?

Navbar code:

```
const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
  const { status } = useSession()

  return (
    <header className="fixed top-0 z-10 w-full select-none backdrop-blur-sm">
      <nav className="relative flex items-center justify-between gap-2 p-2 md:px-[3rem] lg:px-[5rem] xl:px-[15rem] 2xl:px-[24rem]">
        {status !== 'loading' && <MobileMenu />}
        <div className="hidden items-center gap-1 md:flex">
          <MyLink
            href="/"
            icon={<HiBookOpen className="icon" />}
            className="flex items-center gap-1 font-bold"
          >
            Archives
          </MyLink>
        </div>
        {status !== 'loading' && (
          <>
            <SearchBar />
            <div className="flex items-center gap-1 ">
              <ThemeToggler />
              <DesktopMenu />
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const status: "authenticated" | "loading" | "unauthenticated"
```

"status" can take 3 values. this logic `status !== 'loading'` is not correct because if it is not loading, it can be either "authenticated" or "unauthenticated". In both cases you are assuming that it is authenticated. Instead, you should be adding logic based on "data'

```
// changing the data to session
const { data: session } = useSession()
```

Now check `if session` then render the authenticated template if not render unauthenticated template.

Comment: That's true but I'm using "status" to hide those components while is loading, each component (MobileMenu and DesktopMenu) handles what to show if the user is authenticated or not.
I'm trying to reduce the time that takes to know if the user is authenticated or not to avoid layout shifting